# Maven Custom Plugin Creation and Execution

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I am trying to create a custom parameter less plugin by referring to create simple mojo creation instructions by apache in the below link.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#

But I am unable to run the same using maven goal. Kindly suggest what I am missing. As I am new to maven and there aren't many tutorials on custom mavem plugin creation. Any suggestions on this topic will be helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

```
pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

  <name>Sample Parameter-less Maven Plugin</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- dependencies to annotations -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>sayhi</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

GreetingMojo.java

package sample.plugin.hello_maven_plugin;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;

/**
 * Says "Hi" to the user.
 *
 */
@Mojo( name = "sayhi")
public class GreetingMojo extends AbstractMojo
{
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        getLog().info( "Hello, world." );
        System.out.println("My first maven plugin.");
    }
}
```

I am trying to run the pom.xml using package command and mvn install command.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the goal? How do you run maven (e.g. is the goal configured in the POM as an execution, or on the command line)?

Comment: When I run maven build using package command I get error like could not find artifact sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Did you `mvn install` the plugin before using it in another project?

Comment: Actually I am trying to create a  plugin so that I can use it in another project. I am facing the issue while creating it.

Comment: In the plugin project run `mvn install`. After you `mvn install` the plugin you need to declare the plugin as a build plugin in a different maven project. Then from the other project you can run the plugin goal, either by configuring the plugin in the POM file, or executing the goal from the command line.

Comment: Thanks this clears up my confusion on how to execute the plugin but when I tried mvn install in the plugin I am getting the same error couldn't find artifact sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Getting the error from where? The plugin or the other project? Please update your question to include your POM file configurations and the commands you're trying to execute, as well as the specific error you are getting.

Comment: Hi Jake, I have updated the code as instructed. Kindly let me know if I missed something in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you shouldn't execute the plugin goal in the plugin you are trying to build. The reason you cannot build the plugin with `mvn install` is because you have configured maven to expect the plugin to already be built.

This section belongs in a different POM file, not the plugin POM file.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>sayhi</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

After you have removed this section from the plugin POM you can run `mvn install` to install your plugin locally. Once installed you can re-add the section to the POM if you really wanted to, but ideally you would add it to a completely different maven project and execute maven in that project.

Comment: Thanks Jake. You are life saver. God bless.

Comment: Hi Jake, I am able to generate the plugin successfully but when i am trying to import the plugin in a new maven project by adding the below code :<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>sayhi</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>   I am receiving an error saying no plugin is available.